# JavaScript synchronization and critical sections in event handlers

Tags: javascript, synchronization, dom-events

I have a function which is an event handler for `websocket.onmessage`, now since the server can send multiple messages (one after another) and each message will trigger that event, and since the function block may take a few seconds (a lot of rendering going on inside), the function may be called again while the first function call is still running. 
I need a critical block in this function in some cases so that the second call will only start the critical section when the first call ends, what's considered a 'best practice' for implementing locks in JavaScript?

Comment: Did you test? javascript is single threaded, which means if something blocks everything else waits until it's done; you should not need locks at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since js is single-threaded, you can't really do locks. Well, you *can* but you *shouldn't*.

One idea might be to keep a status variable.

Your function will be called on each onmessage, but you only do something if the variable is set to false. If so, you set it to true and when its done, set it back to false.

```
var handler; //expose outside the closure
(function(){
    var busy = false;

    handler = function(){
        if( !busy ){
            busy = true;

            //do rendering stuff

            busy = false;
        }
    }
})();
```

Obviously, adapt this idea to your own needs.

Comment: Actually I thought about this solution myself, but the thing is that I need the data that is being sent from the server (e.g. the one that the client gets in the ```onmessage``` event handler.
That means that I probably should keep each data object which is not being "handled" now inside some kind of buffer or queue, and after I finish with the current onmessage data, start taking care of the ones that came after it but couldn't be handled. But thought there might be another way for this. Also if JavaScript is single threaded, how is it even possible that things work simultaneously?

Comment: They don't actually work simultaneously. If your callback functions in events aren't doing a lot of work, it appears simultaneous, but its not really. If you setup 2 event handlers, and have the callback in #1 in a loop that runs for 10 seconds before exiting, the event handlers for #2 won't fire.

Comment: So isn't it safe to say that even if the server is sending messages to the client during the time onmessage event handler is running, the callback for those messages will only be executed after the current one ends?

Comment: Yes. Events queue up automatically and dispatch in turn after the previous event handler completes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery Socket https://github.com/flowersinthesand/jquery-socket as it has a callback for the message event.

```
message(data, [callback])
```

This means you can get the next message after the first has completed.

EXAMPLE:

```
websocket.onmessage(data, function(){
  //get next message
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS is multithreaded only if you use webworkers. I don't know if websockets are even allowed on worker threads because of the lack of synchronization available, but if you set up all your websockets from the main thread, the events will all fire in order on the main thread, so you do not have to perform any blocking or synchronization yourself (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333676/parallel-programming-synchronization-using-javascript-web-workers) on synchronization in JS)

Comment: workers don't make JS multi-threaded... Workers represent separate processes, that, through the browser implementation (JS engine ~= virtual machine), can communicate with each other. They don't share memory, so they're not really threads, more like separate processes or modules, even

Comment: Web workers may have more in common with processes from an architectural standpoint, and even more so in the JS virtual machine, but they are actually threads in most if not all implementations, and therefore JS is multi-threaded. Sharing memory is not a requirement of multi-threadedness. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker#Overview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh549259.aspx)

Comment: JS isn't multi-threaded, nor is it single-threaded. That's my point: JS, as a language, doesn't define any threading model. Historically, all browser implementations of JS are single threaded. Because the requirements of todays webapps, browsers add the Worker API (meaning: it's not part of JS, just like the DOM API isn't part of JS). Saying that JS is only multi-threaded when using workers is like saying people are only visible when the sun is out... at night, in the middle of nowhere, that might seem to be the case, but that doesn't make it an absolute truth