# HTML5 Webworker Startup Synchronization Guarantees

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, web-worker

I have a bit of javascript I want to run in a webworker, and I am having a hard time understanding the correct approach to getting them to work in lock-step.  I invoke the WebWorker from the main script as in the following simplified script:

```
// main.js
werker = new Worker("webWorkerScaffold.js");

// #1
werker.onmessage = function(msgObj){
    console.log("Worker Reply")
    console.log(msgObj);
    doSomethingWithMsg(msgObj);
};
werker.onerror = function(err){
    console.log("Worker Error:");
    console.log(err);
};

werker.postMessage("begin");
```

Then the complimentary worker script looks like the following:

```
// webWorkerScaffold.js
var doWorkerStuffs = function(msg){};  // Omitted

// #2
onmessage = function (msgObj){
    // Messages in will always be json                                                                                                                                  
    if (msgObj.data.msg === "begin")
        doWorkerStuffs();
};
```

This code (the actual version) works as expected, but I am having a difficult time confirming it will always perform correctly.  Consider the following:

- The "new Worker()" call is made, spawning a new thread.
- The spawned thread is slow to load (lets say hangs at "// #2")
- The parent thread does "werker.postMessage..." with no recipient
- ... ?

The same applies in the reverse direction, where I might change the worker script to make noise outward once it is setup internally, under that scenario the main thread could hang at "// #1" and miss the incoming message as it dosen't have its comm's up.

Is there some way to guarantee that these scripts move forward in a lock-step way?

What I am really looking for is a zmq-like REP/REQ semantic, where one or the other blocks (or calls back) when 1:1 transactions can take place.

Comment: Loosely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333676/parallel-programming-synchronization-using-javascript-web-workers